# Norm and matrix exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

> Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R^{n}},\mathbb{R^{m}})$ and $A=[a_{ij}] \in \mathcal{M}_{m\times n}$ the matrix asocciated to $T$ (relative to the canonical base). Let $$\mu =: \max_{i \in [m], \, j \in [n]} |a_{ij}|$$ Prove that $$\mu \leq \| T \| \leq \mu \sqrt{mn}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- $\ \|T\|=\sup_\limits{\|u\|=1,\|v\|=1\\}|u^\top Tv|\ $.
- If $\ |a_{st}|=\max \big\{|a_{ij}|: i=1,...,m; j=1,...,n \big\}\ $, $\ u^*_i=\delta_{is}\ $, and $\ v^*_i=\delta_{it}\ $, then $\ |\,u^{*\top} Tv^*\,|=\mu\ $.
- By the Cauchy-Schwartz inequalty,
  \begin{align}    \|Tv\|^2&=\sum_{i=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}v_j\right)^2\\
  &\le\sum_{i=1}^m\|v\|^2\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2\ .
      \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

For any matrix $A$ the following inequality holds

$$ \|A \|_{\text{max}} \leq \| A\|_{2} \leq \sqrt{mn}\|A\|_{\text{max}} $$

where $\|A\|_{\text{max}} = \displaystyle \max_{ij} |a_{ij}| $. When you set $\mu = \|A \|_{\text{max}}$ we get

$$ \mu \leq \| A\|_{2} \leq \mu  \sqrt{mn}$$

It comes from Hölder's inequality when $p=q=\infty$